# Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: php, laravel

I cann't input variable on column, I have this on controller

```
public function save()
{
$book = new Book;
$ta = DB::select('SELECT MAX(ta) from book');
$book->ta=$ta;
$book->save();
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should more describe about what do you want to do excatly.

Comment: I think select function returns array, use var_dump on $ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the result as an array, from which you only need the first (and only) element

```
$book = new Book;
$result = DB::select('SELECT MAX(ta) AS ta FROM book');
$book->ta = $result[0]->ta;
$book->save();
```

Or you can use the query builder a bit more and do this

```
$book = new Book;
$result = DB::table('book')->selectRaw('MAX(ta) AS ta')->first();
$book->ta = $result->ta;
$book->save();
```